# What is another way of saying "back then"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Such as referring to a previous time or the past.

For instance,

> "The reason why is because **back then**, instead of drinking raw milk
>   as a staple food, they turned most of their milk into cheese."

Comment: _back in the day_ is a common substitute.

Comment: Say *when* "... until the late 19th century/1920s..." or " about 100 years ago..." or whatever period is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- "in the past"
- "in historic times"
- "in olden days"
- "in old times"
- "in the good old days"
- "in the golden age" (this may be too specific; refers to a specific period)
- "bygone days"
- "former days"
- "days of old"
- "days of yore"

Comment: Once upon a time

Comment: Some of the suggested expressions, such as 'in olden days', convey a sentimentalised attitude to the past. If you are making a serious historical point, it would be better to do as Mari-Lou says and state which historical period you mean.

Comment: While the context indicates a historical tone, we would need additional context to see if this is in a setting of historical fact, historical fiction, dialog between characters speaking about the past, and so on. In light of this I provided sentimental phrases as additional options.